# JSP on eclipse: applying inline css in a conditional statement

Tags: css, eclipse, jsp

I have a navigation bar in a .jsp file whereby I want it where if an imported java condition returns null then (using inline css), set the link in the navigation to display:none; else display:block; This is what I came up with so far but eclipse doesn't seem to like it when I add none and block:

```
<li><a style="display:<%if(Settings.getInstance().getExternalDataLocation()!= null){
        none;" 
        }else{
        block;"}%> 
</li>
```

The following errors also seem to appear under the red lines of 'none' and 'block':

```
- Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete 
 LocalVariableDeclaration
- Syntax error on token "block", } expected
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
```

I'm sure the errors are self explanatory but I still cant seem to get my head round resolving them or even knowing if I am missing the correct syntax. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I guess you have a misplaced `"`. Try this: style="display:'<%if(Settings.getInstance().getExternalDataLocation()!= null){
        none;
        }else{
        block;}%'">

Comment: I guess you have a misplaced ". Try this: style="display:<%if(Settings.getInstance().getExternalDataLocation()!= null){ none; }else{ block;}%">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead,

```
   <li>
        <%if(Settings.getInstance().getExternalDataLocation()!= null){%>
        <a style="display:none;">
        <%}else{%>
        <a style="display:block;">
        <%}%>        
    </li>
```

But however using scriptlets are considered to be bad since a decade . try to use jstl or el

see this post for more info [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick responses. I have tried your solution san and it has worked successfully and is far more comprehensible then my initial idea. I did not realise how much scriptlets are discouraged and deliver such limitations. I probably will look more into the alternatives you have mentioned to avoid hindering my project as a whole. Thanks again.